# Intel Pin:Invalid REG for IARG_REG_VALUE reg: xmm0

Tags: intel-pin

I'm making a program to trace the program, but I am having trouble with the error like the title.
Is there anyone who can understand something?

```
INS_InsertCall(ins, action, AFUNPTR(RegOpnd::at_call),
            IARG_PTR, data,
            IARG_PTR, this,
            IARG_REG_VALUE, reg_,
            IARG_END);
```

I checked that IARG_REG_VALUE was not compatible with xmm registers.
How can I get the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#gga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451dabe70796bf61230dac3ea1deaf4983c46) says:

> this cannot be used to retrieve the value of registers whose size is larger than ADDRINT (e.g. x87 FPU/XMM/YMM/ZMM/opmask)

You have two options,  either:

- Test for the type of the register and use [`IARG_REG_CONST_REFERENCE`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#gga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451da817f3f2fe8c0c536daa86deb55126c25) (or `IARG_REG_REFERENCE` if you wish to modify the register).
- Get the CPU context (using [`IARG_CONST_CONTEXT`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#gga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451dad3e65d643a63acb09d12b8538434ca45) or `IARG_CONTEXT` if you wish to modify any register in it) and inspect the registers in the context.

I guess that the first option is the more meaningful one, so it should go approximately like the code below:

**Warning**: code below has not been tested / compiled...

Instrumentation:

```
const unsigned int opnd_count =  INS_OperandCount(ins);
for(unsigned int i=0; i < opnd_count;i++)
{
    if (INS_OperandIsReg(ins,i))
    {
        REG r = INS_OperandReg(ins,i);
        if ((r))
        {
            INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)xmm_arg, 
                           IARG_REG_CONST_REFERENCE, r,
                           IARG_REG_REFERENCE, r, // you might remove this one if you don't modify the reg.
                           IARG_UINT32, i,
                           IARG_UINT32, (r-REG_XMM_BASE), // note: REG_XMM_BASE = REG_XMM0
                           IARG_END);
        }

    }
}
```

Analysis:

```
// regConstRef: const reference on the register
// regRef: reference on the register
// opnd_indx: operand index (0 for the 1st inst. op.; 1 for the 2nd inst. op.)
// regno: register number: 0 = XMM0; 1 = XMM1, etc.
VOID xmm_arg(PIN_REGISTER* regConstRef, PIN_REGISTER* regRef, UINT32 opnd_indx, UINT32 regno)
{
    // just "dump" the register
    std::cout << "XMM" << regno << " operand_index: " << opnd_indx << " ";
    for(unsigned int i=0;i< MAX_DWORDS_PER_PIN_REG;i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << regConstRef->dword[i] << " ";
    }  
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,comment. I will try to run it with code.I finally want to correspond to XMM / YMM / ZMM registers.