# I want to compile glibc with sse disabled

Tags: gcc, x86-64, sse, glibc

I thought that I do not want to use SSE instructions in libc library functions like `strcpy()`.

So I attempted to build from source code with option `-mno-sse`.
However, I got an error like the following, I could not make it.

```
 ../stdlib/bits/stdlib-float.h: In function ‘atof’:
 ../stdlib/bits/stdlib-float.h:26:1: error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
```

Is there anyone who knows the cause?
Is there anyone who can solve it ?

Comment: why do you think you don't want to use SSE instructions?

Comment: @GradyPlayer The only thing I can think is that the OP is writing some sort of kernel code where SIMD register usage is banned or highly discouraged.

Comment: well the calling convention is different for syscalls anyway... maybe there is an attribute decorator... also you could make them variadic, and everything would be pushed onto the stack

Comment: @GradyPlayer This is what I am working on right now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312772/intel-pininvalid-reg-for-iarg-reg-value-reg-xmm0

In the process of addressing this problem, I got a question and asked a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x86-64 System V ABI's calling convention returns `float` and `double` in XMM registers.

SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.  64-bit code can assume it without checking, so the standard calling convention uses it.  You never need to disable SSE2 for compatibility with hardware.

To compile without SSE for x86-64, you'll need a compiler that can use an alternate calling convention for floating point, or you'll need to build glibc without *any* floating point args or return values if that's even possible.  (FP code within a function is fine; gcc knows how to fall back to x87 if SSE isn't available, even in 64-bit code.)

Even then, there might not *be* a hand-written x86-64 asm version of `strcpy` without SSE2 in glibc, only for 32-bit x86.  So glibc may not compile for that reason even if you did avoid the `float`/`double` problem.  And if it does, the generic C `strcpy` will suck for performance compared to SSE2.

---

**It should work fine to build glibc for 32-bit x86 without SSE**.  The i386 System V ABI's calling convention passes FP args on the stack, and returns them in x87 `st0`.

SSE is an optional extension to 32-bit x86; not all 32-bit-only CPUs have it, so toolchains and libraries do need to support being compiled without it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there no choice but to change the compiler to another, or change the source code of glibc ...

Comment: @pinenight: I don't know if there's a way to get gcc to use an alternate non-SSE ABI for x86-64.  Even if there was, you wouldn't be able to call any `float` or `double` functions from normal code, so many programs that wanted to use this custom libc would have to be recompiled, too.  (`libm` is a separate file, but many programs that use FP at all use `printf` with FP formats and that's in `libc`.)

Comment: If you want to disable SSE/SSE2 only for some specific hand-written asm functions (like memcpy and strcpy), you could maintain binary compatibility, but you would probably need to tweak the source code to disable the normal dispatching to AVX / SSE versions when available.  `strcpy` without SSE2 is not going to be efficient, but `memcpy` with `rep movsb` is not bad on CPUs with ERMSB.

Comment: If anything was going to work for 64-bit code, perhaps `-mfpmath=387`, but IDK if that could override the calling convention.  There might be other GCC args.  The functions with float/double args or return values of course wouldn't be ABI-compatible with code compiled normally, but the other functions hopefully would be.